# should I reindex the old domain after moving to a new domain

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I performed a redirect 4 months ago and my rank is not coming back till now.

**old domain performance in the last 6 months**

[image]

**New domain performance in the last 6 months**

[image]

Should I reindex the old domain again although it shows a page with a redirect?

[image]

Or it needs more than 4 months to point the old URL with the same rank to the new domain

**Please, Please help me to get back my old rank**

---

## update

I have performed redirect 301 in haccess using **`RedirectMatch 301`** and each URL in the old domain redirect correctly to the new one

also, I used the move tool in Google console as shown below

[image]

Comment: Did you use the [Change of Address Tool in Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, I did kindly check the updated question, and thank you for your usual help

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Could you also please open this Question, it has been updated as you requested https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129104/index-issue-for-the-migrated-domain

Comment: When you say you want to "reindex your site," what are you proposing doing?   Reversing the redirects?